# Overflow:auto; not working properly in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have one container to show users activity. I set overflow auto to this container. it is working nice in chrome, FF and etc. but in IE7, content overflowing from this container. it will not hidden. check this below

[image]

```
in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nUQ8V/1/

or code :

**CSS:**
----------------------------------
p {
    margin:0;  font-family:arial; font-size:12px;
}
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:2px solid #ddd;
}

.inner {
    padding:10px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
    position:relative;
}

.title { 
    font-weight:bold;
}

**html** 
------------------------------
<div class="container">
    <div class='inner'>
        <p class="title">Gopi Buyer Viewed</p>
        <p>Sri Ragavendra Castle</p>
        <p>Korattur</p>
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
        <p class="title">Gopi Buyer Viewed</p>
        <p>Sri Ragavendra Castle</p>
        <p>Korattur</p>
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
        <p class="title">Gopi Buyer Viewed</p>
        <p>Sri Ragavendra Castle</p>
        <p>Korattur</p>
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
        <p class="title">Gopi Buyer Viewed</p>
        <p>Sri Ragavendra Castle</p>
        <p>Korattur</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nUQ8V/5/

### use ie7 inline hack :

```
.inner {
    padding:10px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
    position:relative;
    *position:*static;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the position:relative; to this below class

```
.inner {
    padding:10px 0;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
   /* position:relative; */
}
```

It will work fine in all browsers.